# Install new XCode recover previous SDK ( deprecated )

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, version, deprecated

For each new release of Xcode, you lose the previous SDK.
On Xcode 3.2.5 , iOS SDK is 4.2 , but you lose the previous SDK 3.x
I understand Apple want to reduce the fragmentation.

I tried an old trick. Install the new Xcode in a new folder "*Xcode*" .
From the former Xcode copy paste from `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs` 
all the SDK version to the new Xcode `/Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs` in the same directory.

Then for the the simulators do the same with the path

```
Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

then just restart XCode and you are ready to go.

Now in Xcode, the 'missing' simulator appear. But when I run them I get the message
"The simulated application quit. Click Relaunch to try again."
I choose "*Switch SDK*" button to the correct one. But I get the same error.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What others have been doing is to keep an installation of XCode that supports 3.x, and have that installed in a separate directory.

I have kept some old 3.0 devices, such as the original iPhone and a Touch, and use those for testing.  But at some point you're probably going to have to just say that users of your software have to have iOS4 or higher - there are a lot of compelling frameworks and abilities (like blocks).  There are not very many original iPhones compared to the number of devices that can migrate to iOS4 now...

The real test will be how many iPads convert to iOS4.2, as I know a lot of people never even connect them to a computer.  That will be the thing that might sway you to really shift to iOS4 fully or not.